# Git add "child" repos as regular files?

Tags: git, git-submodules

this is my first question on here, sorry if it's bad.

I backup some of my home files using git, that includes vim plugins, which I often keep as a git repo, so I have several git repos in my own repo.
Sadly these subrepos are not being added when I use

```
 git add . -A
```

on a copy of my home folder.

Somewhat solutions I found:

- I heard that there's a way to add submodules, but for some reason they get put in the root of the repo, so I'd have to manually move them after adding them every time, and removing submodules also is a pain in the ass if I want to change something.
- Another way would be to remove the .git folder of the vim plugins, but that would mean losing information of where the plugin is from and would make pulling changes harder.

Is there any other way to do this?

I would be ok if I could add every subrepo as regular files, with the drawback that changes would be tracked twice.

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something, but you should be able to add an existing child repo as a submodule with `git submodule add ./my/repo/path`.

Comment: Like @user2062950 said, you're approaching it the wrong way, the way he said should be OK. Also the submodules being added to the Git repo is just telling Git that there's another Git repo there, anything inside that Git repo (i.e. the submodule) is handled by the submodule. Hope that makes sense. :)

Comment: @Greduan again, the submodule will be located in the root of the repo, so it wouldn't represent my exact setup. I tried changing the .gitmodule entry so its located elsewhere but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Greduan's and my comments:

You can add a local git repo as a submodule with `git submodule add <repo> <path>`.

According to Git SCM docs on [`submodule add`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule):

> This requires at least one argument: `<repository>`. The **optional** argument `<path>` is the **relative location** for the cloned submodule to exist in the superproject.

**TL;DR: if the `<repo>` and `<path>` are the same, you can avoid cloning the child repo to the parent repo**

---

#### Now, for an example (I was curious to see how this actually works, figured I'll try it and post my results):

Let's say we have a parent repo in `./`, and a child repo in `./some/folder/child-repo`.

You can add the submodule without unnecessarily cloning it via:

```
git submodule add ./some/folder/child-repo ./some/folder/child-repo #same location
```

This will add the `child-repo` as a submodule at it's current location.

Git will output something like: `Adding existing repo at 'some/folder/child-repo' to the index`.

If you run `git status`, you should see two new files ready to be committed:

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       new file:   .gitmodules
#       new file:   some/folder/child-repo
#
```

`.gitmodules` is the file that describes your module, the other file is the child repo representation.

Commit the submodule to the parent repo: `git commit -m 'add child-repo as submodule'`

At this point, any commits you make in the *child-repo* will show up in the **parent** repo like this:

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   some/folder/child-repo (new commits)
#
```

You can then run `git submodule update` to update the parent repo. And there you have it - no unnecessary duplication or extra commits :)

*Caveat*: If you need to work with the child repo after you ran `submodule update` in the parent, you'll find the child-repo will be in a **detached HEAD** state. This is documented in the [`git submodule`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) manual **update** section.

You can fix that with `git checkout master`(or whatever branch you're working with) in the child repo.

Comment: Interesting.. So what happens? And which version of Git are you using?

Comment: I use version 1.8.4.
When I add the submodule and checkout the parent repo at another client the directory of the child repo is just empty, but the module is in the .gitmodules file. It makes sense, since it's just pointing to an empty directory (itself) on that client.
What somewhat works is having the submodule added with the original repo adress (like github or what ever), but that only works when you use the vanilla repo, since it fetches from the original repo. (I have an modified dwm repo, which i can't track this way)

Comment: when you checked out the repo at another client, did you run `git submodule update`?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest switching to [vim-addon-manager](https://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-manager) or [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) to hold third-party plugins. The main idea is that you put into your vimrc names of the plugins you want to install, but configure VAM/Vundle to install them to location not tracked by VCS. Then if you want to recover from backup you allow (VAM) or explicitely ask (Vundle, if I am not mistaking) to install all plugins you have listed in your configuration.

VAM in documentation even has a function (listed under [Installation](http://vimpluginloader.sourceforge.net/doc/vim-addon-manager-getting-started.txt.html#VAM-installation) section) that will first check whether VAM is already installed, install it if it was not and then proceed with plugins.

This variant removes the need for submodules in place of resolving issues with them.

You may also may find interesting [comparison between VAM and other plugins with similar purpose](http://vimpluginloader.sourceforge.net/doc/vim-addon-manager-additional-documentation.txt.html#VAM-comparison).